# When trying to execute Sonarqube on a Jenkins pipeline I get a "Project root configuration file: NONE" log message

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to learn the basics of sonarqube, I have set it up on my jenkins pipeline (which uses MSBuild to compile the project) and the set a step to execute SonarQube but after reading and watching a few tutorials and the documentation itself I think I got a bit lost as when my pipeline finishes executing I go to my SonarQube server and I my project says `The main branch has no lines of code.`. I get the following log when running the sonarqube step on my jenkins:

```
00:10:43.369  Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: SonarQube
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
00:10:43.653  
00:10:43.653  C:\Users\anton\.jenkins\workspace\Boston>C:\Users\anton\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\Sonnar_scanner\sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170\bin\sonar-scanner.bat   
00:10:43.653  INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Users\anton\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\Sonnar_scanner\sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
00:10:43.653  INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
00:10:43.653  INFO: SonarScanner 4.4.0.2170
00:10:43.653  INFO: Java 1.8.0_261 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
00:10:43.653  INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
00:10:44.230  INFO: User cache: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
00:10:44.230  INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Users\anton\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\Sonnar_scanner\sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
00:10:44.230  INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
00:10:44.230  INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.5.1
00:10:44.230  INFO: Default locale: "es_ES", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
00:10:44.783  WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
00:10:44.784  INFO: Load global settings
00:10:44.784  INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=40ms
00:10:44.784  INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXWnoupqHjnRwWgEnmvK
00:10:44.784  INFO: User cache: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
00:10:44.784  INFO: Load/download plugins
00:10:44.784  INFO: Load plugins index
00:10:44.784  INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=26ms
00:10:44.784  INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=48ms
00:10:45.037  INFO: Process project properties
00:10:45.037  INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=6ms
00:10:45.037  INFO: Execute project builders
00:10:45.037  INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
00:10:45.037  INFO: Project key: Boston
00:10:45.037  INFO: Base dir: C:\Users\anton\.jenkins\workspace\Boston
00:10:45.037  INFO: Working dir: C:\Users\anton\.jenkins\workspace\Boston\.scannerwork
00:10:45.301  INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'Boston'
00:10:45.301  INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'Boston' (done) | time=10ms
00:10:45.301  INFO: Load quality profiles
00:10:45.301  INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=27ms
00:10:45.301  INFO: Auto-configuring with CI 'Jenkins'
00:10:45.301  INFO: Load active rules
00:10:46.241  INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=787ms
00:10:46.241  INFO: Indexing files...
00:10:46.241  INFO: Project configuration:
00:10:46.241  INFO: 0 files indexed
00:10:46.241  INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module Boston
00:10:46.241  INFO: Load metrics repository
00:10:46.241  INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=12ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily]
00:10:46.807  INFO: No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=1ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
00:10:46.807  INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
00:10:46.807  INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=1ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=0ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
00:10:46.807  INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: SCM Publisher is disabled
00:10:46.807  INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 0 files
00:10:46.807  INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=0ms
00:10:46.807  INFO: Analysis report generated in 48ms, dir size=82 KB
00:10:46.807  INFO: Analysis report compressed in 10ms, zip size=10 KB
00:10:47.060  INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 26ms
00:10:47.060  INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=Boston
00:10:47.060  INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
00:10:47.060  INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXWt8eSC9o0F9NdVJGJP
00:10:47.060  INFO: Executing post-job 'Final report'
00:10:47.060  INFO: Turn debug info on to get more details (sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.verbose=true ...).
00:10:47.060  INFO: Analysis total time: 2.118 s
00:10:47.060  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:10:47.060  INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
00:10:47.060  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:10:47.060  INFO: Total time: 3.274s
00:10:47.060  INFO: Final Memory: 21M/549M
00:10:47.060  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

and I think the main issue is the line where it says `Project root configuration file: NONE` I have created a sonar-project.properties file in the root folder of my project and it has the following configuration:

```
sonar.projectKey=Boston
sonar.projectName=Boston
sonar.dotnet.visualStudio.solution=Age3DE.sln
sonar.scm.disabled=true

sonar.sources=./Source
sonar.language=c++
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

But yet I cannot make it work. I do not know what I am doing wrong, should the sonar-project.properties be set anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If the source files are present in **Sources** directory, then your **sonar.sources** should be like this

`sonar.sources=**/Sources/*`

Or

`sonar.sources=Sources/*`

Comment: thanks for answering I have changed it as you told me but I still get the same error:```Project root configuration file: NONE``` I have placed ithe sonar-project.properties on the parent folder of my project is it going anywhere else? shall it goes on the Source folder in side the main folder?

Comment: sonar-project.properties file should be present in root folder only. Could you please tell me, what is the error you can see in sonar UI ?? Also, can you try by giving `sonar.sources=.`

Comment: I tried ```sonar.sources=.``` and I got the same result, as the prject.sln file is in Source folder I tried to set the file in main folder and also inside Source folder which is a direct children of main folder but nothing works

Comment: if I go to my project on the SonarQube UI I see the project has no lines of code, but if I go to activity tab I can see activity at the same time I runned my pipeline

Comment: have you set the correct branch in Jenkins configuration while doing the code checkout ? Sometimes, it happens, you cannot see a lines of code due to this as it has happened for me. After, I have given the correct branch, I can see the lines of code. May I know, which branch you are analyzing for code analysis ?

Comment: I am not doing any code checkout ATM the code is on my machine ATM, I usually works with Perforce but I am running everything locally for learning porpouses